# Add custom property to every item of a collection

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to add a custom property to every item of a collection, but it doesn't show up in the template.

I have a lot of quotations which have a `client_id`. Now I want to fetch the client by the `client_id` and add it to the collection entry. In general, it works when inspecting the populated object with `console.log`, but it doesn't show up in the template.

That's how I tried it:

```
sprocket.QuotationsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'content-inner',

    initialize: function(options) {
      // instantiate Collection
      this.collection = new Quotations();

      // compile Handlebars template
      this.tpl = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
    },

    render: function() {
      var self = this;
      var obj = this.el;

      // get quotations and set data to handlebars template
      $.when(this.collection.fetch()).then(function(quotations) {

        $.each(quotations, function(i, quotation) {

          var loadContact = new Contact({id: quotation.contact_id}).fetch();
          $.when(loadContact).then(function(contact) {
            quotations[i]['contact'] = contact;
          });

        });

        $(obj).html(self.tpl(quotations));

      // if response is empty (no quotations in database), set empty template
      }, function() {
        $(obj).html(self.tpl);
      });

      return this;
    }
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
<div>
  {{#if .}}
    {{#each .}}
      {{number}} <!-- this works -->
      {{contact}} <!-- this doesn't work -->
      {{contact.name}} <!-- this doesn't work too -->
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: did you drop a breakpoint on `quotations[i]['contact'] = contact;`?  is `contact` what you expected it to be?  I'm guessing not...

Comment: As I said: `In general, it works when inspecting the populated object with console.log` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the callback that actually changes the data inside the `Quotation.attribute.contact` (ie. your `quotations[i]['contact'] = contact;` line) is being executed after fetching the `Contact` which happens to be after the template is being rendered.

```
$.each(quotations, function(i, quotation) {

  var loadContact = new Contact({id: quotation.contact_id}).fetch();
  // This is the callback that is being executed after the backend responds
  $.when(loadContact).then(function(contact) {
     quotations[i]['contact'] = contact;
  });

});

// This is the template rendering which is before the server has time to respond
$(obj).html(self.tpl(quotations));
```

Render instead the template after all `Contacts` are being fetched and added to `Quotations`.

A quick way to solve this:

1. Make the loop which load all the `Contacts` inside a function that contains a callback.
2. Call the callback after all `Contacts` have loaded.
3. The callback should render the template.

This is a personal opinion and in no way an answer to this question: I don't like the data logic with the backend and the view rendering and logic in the same class. I use `Backbone.Marionette` to split the `View` and the `Controller` in two different entities loosely coupled by events. Only the `Controller` is aware of the `View` and only the `View` is aware of the `DOM`.

Comment: Aahh, thank you very much. I think I'm going to collect all single `Contact` fetches with RSVP and handle them in one function to get a callback for rendering the template with the new data. I'll have a look at `Backbone.Marionette`, thank you!

Comment: My pleasure :) Yes take a look at `Backbone.Marionette`! It holds your hand a bit more, but in a good way.